# JAXB parent class tag not wanted

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am converting java class into XML file using JAXB library. I dont want to create parent class tag
Example
My Main Class is ComponentDTO.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "flow")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ComponentDto {
    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "input", type = ActivityDto.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "action", type = ActivityAction.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "dropdown", type = Dropdown.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "alert", type = ActivityAlert.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "windows", type = ActivityWindow.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "script", type = Javascript.class),
    })
    List<ChildDto> dtos;

    public interface ChildDto {}

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @XmlRootElement(name = "input")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class ActivityDto implements ChildDto {    
        @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
        private String name;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @XmlRootElement(name = "action")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class ActivityAction implements ChildDto {    
        @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
        private String name;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @XmlRootElement(name = "dropdown")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class Dropdown implements ChildDto {    
        @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
        private String name;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @XmlRootElement(name = "alert")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class ActivityAlert implements ChildDto {    
        @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
        private String name;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @XmlRootElement(name = "windows")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class ActivityWindow implements ChildDto {    
        @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
        private String name;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @XmlRootElement(name = "script")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class Javascript implements ChildDto {    
        @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
        private String name;
    }
}
```

and when i create object for ComponentDTO and then generate xml for this class then it will generate like this

```
<flow>
    <dtos>
        <input name="test"/>
    </dtos>
    <dtos>
        <action name="test"/>
    </dtos>
    <dtos>
        <dropdown name="test"/>
    </dtos>
    <dtos>
        <alert name="test"/>
    </dtos>
    <dtos>
        <windows name="test"/>
    </dtos>
    <dtos>
        <script name="test"/>
    </dtos>
</flow>
```

but i want result like this

```
<flow>
    <input name="test"/>
    <action name="test"/>
    <dropdown name="test"/>
    <alert name="test"/>
    <windows name="test"/>
    <script name="test"/>
</flow>
```

How can i do that?